# Performance Counter Read On Remote Machine - Cost

Tags: windows, remote, performance-monitoring

What I am after is what performance hit is there on the remote machine I am reading a performance counter on?  For example, I have a web server that reports some performance counter information on another machine.  I want to know what type of performance hit the remote machine takes every time the web server tries to read a performance counter.  Does this vary based on which counter you are reading?  Is there a standard formula?

The reason I ask is because we have multiple people monitoring the same machine real time using performance counters.  I sometimes wonder if we are contributing to the problem and adding extra load on the remote machine we are monitoring.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely find something in the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) suite that will allow you to monitor the load caused by counter query routines.

There is no basic formula. Without know what you're querying and where it comes from, I can't begin to guess.

Comment: In this case I'm querying Processor, % Processor Time, _Total of a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer stated, it depends on what you're monitoring and it also depends on how frequently you're monitoring as well.  While I can't speak about other tools, the open source tool collectl is something I wrote and which I took great pains to optimize.  Even though it is written in perl, it can sample hundreds of counters with < 0.1% overhead at a sampling rate of every 10 seconds.  For most users they don't even know it's there and I could easily imaging multiple copies being invisible as well.  I'd think other 'native' tools would be even more efficient but might not offer the breadth of functionality collectl does.
-mark